# Use Uri from Activity in Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, uri

I've got database with Uri values and i want to send email from adapter. The problem is when i try to send message i've got: **UID 10541 does not have permission to content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2Fbilet24379308248321183796.pdf [user 0]; you could obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs**

```
   try {

                                val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                                emailIntent.type = "plain/text"
                                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf(kindleEmailAddress))
                                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title)
                                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, att)
                                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
                                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending email..."))

                             
                            }
                            catch (t: Throwable) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Request failed try again: $t", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
```

I tried to add `grantUriPermission` before Intent declaration but it doesn't work.

```
      context.grantUriPermission(context.packageName, att,
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

Comment: "I've got database with Uri values" -- how did you get those values? If the answer is `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, you need to call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver` right when you get the `Uri` in `onActivityResult()`. Otherwise, [your rights to access the content will lapse](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare takePersistableUriPermission() works perfectly. Your blog is awesome. Many usefull information :)